# Probability of including one person and not including an other one when creating a 4 person group

Tags: probability, combinatorics

In a classroom there are 24 students, including Joe, Robert and Oliver.
We randomly assemble a four-student group (The order does not matter).
What is the probability that the 4 student group will include Oliver but not Robert.

I have tried removing one student (Robert) and calculating the possibilities with Oliver. I did: ${23 \choose 4}$ - ${22 \choose 4}$ = 1540, which I divided by ${23 \choose 4}$ = 1540/8855 (but it doesn't seem right)

Comment: what have you tried
?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Also, please read [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: I added my attempts.

Comment: You did not account for the fact that Oliver must be in the group, which means you only have three additional people to select.  To find the number of favorable case, you must subtract the number of groups containing both Oliver and Robert from the number which contain Oliver.  With that in mind, read Amit Kumar Basistha's answer.  If you need further clarification, ask him to elaborate on his answer.

Comment: Number of ways to choose $3$ persons along with Oliver is ${23 \choose 3}$ but you need to subtract ${22 \choose 2}$ which is number of possible groups of four in which Robert is with Oliver. But I would simply notice that ${22 \choose 3}$ is the number of ways of choosing $3$ persons with Oliver _excluding_ Robert. Another way to think - Probability that Oliver is in the group is $4/24$ and probability that Robert is not in the group that Oliver is in is $20/23$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ denote the number of groups that contains Oliver and $B$ denote the number of groups that contains Robert.We are to find $\mid A-B\mid =\mid A \mid -\mid A\cap B\mid $

Now clearly the result is equal to $\binom{23}{3}-\binom{22}{2}=1771-231=1540$

Also $\binom{24}{4}=10626$.

So probability $ =\frac{1540}{10626}=\frac{10}{69} $

Comment: Combination number 3(23) equals 1771 and you wrote 1171. Is that a mistake?

Comment: yes it is.corrected now.thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 2):

Let Oliver in four-student group. Now it will be selecting three students out of $22$, since Robert is not in the group.

P(including Oliver but not Robert)$=\frac{\binom{22}{3}}{\binom{24}{4}}=\frac{10}{69}$